# What is the difference between scene camera and data camera and how to set the FOV?

Tags: scripting, camera

I tried to set the FOV of my camera but could not do it via `bpy.context.scene.camera`. When I tried to access the angle property I got AttributeError, but I found bpy.data.cameras["Camera"] has an angle attribue that I could change. My script now looks like this:

```
def setup_camera():
    camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
    camera.scale = (-1, 1, -1)
    camera.rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
    cam = bpy.data.cameras["Camera"]
    cam.angle_x = 69.4
    cam.angle_y = 42.5
```

I just wanted to know if this is the right way to change the FOV? I guess one is a camera profile the other one is an actual camera?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that familiar with the structure of Blender's type hierarchy, but according to the documentation for Blender's [`Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Object.html) type there is a distinction between the **object** and the objects's **data block**.

```
# From Blender's Documentation:

# Create new lamp datablock
lamp_data = bpy.data.lamps.new(name="New Lamp", type='POINT')

# Create new object with our lamp datablock
lamp_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="New Lamp", object_data=lamp_data)
```

Likewise, `bpy.context.scene.camera` is a Blender `Object` type which has its camera specific attributes stored in it's data block of [`Camera`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Camera.html) type, which can be accessed with the attribute `data`.

```
camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
camera.data.angle_x = math.radians(69.4)  # angle_x and angle_y take radians
```

The properties panel in the user interface is arranged the same way. Values like location, rotation etc. are set in the *Object* tab, type specific values like the Field of View of a camera or shape keys for a mesh are set in the *Data* tab.

You could also have more than one camera in the scene, in which case the cameras could either be accessed as objects in `bpy.data.objects['<name>']` (with the camera data accessible from the objects's data attribute again), or you access the data block directly `bpy.data.cameras['<name>']`.
`bpy.context.scene.camera` would only refer to the active camera of the scene, just like the corresponding entry in the properties panel under the *Scene* tab.

N.B.: I assume `angle_x` and `angle_y` [can't be set independently](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23431/34236) but instead are coupled by the aspect ratio. If you set `angle_x`, `angle_y` will follow suit.

Comment: I saw that question, but I assumed since the api exposes both I can set both. Oh and they take rads that is very good to know